# SharePoint OOTB Web Services asmx to WSDL conversion not working

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, wsdl

I have a problem accessing the web services?wsdl for SharePoint lists, sites etc.

I can see the list of operations using the following URLS:

http://test.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx - returns a list of operations for OOTB Service

http://test.com/_vti_bin/sites.asmx - returns a list of operations for OOTB Service

However, when I try to view WSDL document using the following URLs:

http://test.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl - returns a 404 error

http://test.com/_vti_bin/sites.asmx?wsdl - returns a 404 error

On the test enviroment, I can see the WSDL being returned but on the production it returns 404 errors as mentioned above.

I'm also seeing this message in the logs:

Error on page: http://test.com/_vti_bin/wswsdl.aspx?WSDL
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: There is no Web named "/careers/Pages/_vti_bin/sites.asmx".

It seems that asmx to wsdl coversion is not working well on production enviroment. Any ideas will be appreciated.

I have also made sure to add `"<protocols><add name="Documentation"/></protocols>"` to the WebServices element of web.config of webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could it be possible that in your production environment that the web.config actually configured to remove the Documentation protocol instead of adding it?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815149

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting as the right user i.e. enough rights?

I'd guess its most likely an authentication issue within the IIS, so check the logs there as well.

also check the EventLog for any additional errors.